# In Ruby, how does a class defined in a module know the module's constants?

Tags: ruby, module, constants, hierarchy

I'm trying to understand how a class defined in a module knows the module's constants. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
module Car
  class Wheel
  end

  class Seat
    p Wheel        # Car::Wheel
  end
end
```

I know it's obvious, but since Wheel is nowhere in Seat's hierarchy, I don't understand how it can have access to it.

Comment: It looks to me that Wheel *is* in Seat's hierarchy, as a peer, since they have the same parent namespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reference a class constant, Ruby will look for it first in the same module, and then on the root if it's not found there.

So, since both `Seat` and `Wheel` are in the `Car` module, if you look for `Wheel`, it will first look for `Car::Wheel`, and then for `::Wheel`. Since `Car::Wheel` exists, you get that reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for information on Ruby's *Constant Lookup* rules. Details surrounding this changed in Ruby 1.9, and then changed again in Ruby 1.9.2. You can read [some discussion on this](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-core-google/tree/browse_frm/thread/a92ac835dde22499/16f9e9c857f5ed5b?rnum=1&q=ruby+constant+lookup&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fruby-core-google%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2Fa92ac835dde22499%2F8bbe2800b236d7f7%3Fq%3Druby%2Bconstant%2Blookup%26#doc_16f9e9c857f5ed5b) on the ruby-core mailing list.

Here is an excellent review of some of differences between Ruby 1.8.x, Ruby 1.9, and Ruby 1.9.2: http://jfire.posterous.com/constant-lookup-in-ruby

Comment: Links not working anymore. Would really love to read on the differences. Do you still know other links that work?

Comment: Try searching for "Ruby Constant Lookup 1.9". Here's one article I found: https://jfire.io/blog/2011/01/21/making-sense-of-constant-lookup-in-ruby/