# Why is_a? returns false for Hash class?

Tags: ruby, database, mongoid

Why `is_a?` returns `false` for a `Hash` class?

Example:

```
value = {"x" => 3, "y" => 2}

puts value.class
puts value.is_a?(Hash)
```

Output:

```
Hash
false
```

Im using Ruby 1.9.2

**UPDATED**: full source of my class:

```
class LatLng
  include Mongoid::Fields::Serializable

  attr_reader :lat, :lng

  def serialize(value)
    return if value.nil?

    puts value.class
    puts value.is_a?(Hash)

    if value.is_a?(self.class)
      puts "is geopoint" + value.to_json
      {'lng' => value.lng.to_f, 'lat' => value.lat.to_f}
    elsif value.is_a?(Hash)
      hash = value.with_indifferent_access
      puts "is hash" + value.to_json
      {'lng' => hash['lng'].to_f, 'lat' => hash['lat'].to_f}
    end
  end

  def deserialize(value)
    return if value.nil?

    value.is_a?(self.class) ? value : LatLng.new(value['lat'], value['lng'])
  end

  def initialize(lat, lng)
    @lat, @lng = lat.to_f, lng.to_f
  end

  def [](arg)
    case arg
      when "lat"
        @lat
      when "lng"
        @lng
    end
  end

  def to_a
    [lng, lat]
  end

  def ==(other)
    other.is_a?(self.class) && other.lat == lat && other.lng == lng
  end
end
```

Comment: Everything is ok on ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) (i got a true value)

Comment: Also works here. Can you check if `Hash.new.is_a?(Hash)` also returns false? That would be rather strange.

Comment: May be problems is caused by some gem that overrides Hash

Comment: It works in irb, but not in my sample. I've listed whole class source

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#irb
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > value = {"x" => 3, "y" => 2}
 => {"x"=>3, "y"=>2} 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > value.is_a?(Hash)
 => true
```

try to disable any gems/extensions you have loaded, and try with clean ruby

**UPDATE:**

try `value.is_a?(::Hash)`

**PS:** try to read about [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Ruby) in Ruby. Maybe you should call `value.respond_to?(:key)` instead of `value.is_a?(Hash)`

Comment: It works in irb, but not in my sample. I've listed whole class source

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does this work? (`::Hash`).  Read a post on double colon in Ruby but I don't understand why it would be applicable in this case.

Comment: Zed, Thanks. =) Found same solution.

Comment: By including the module Mongoid::Fields::Serializable means Ruby will look in Mongoid::Fields::Serializable for anything named Hash first, then it will look in Mongoid::Fields for Hash, until it finds Hash.  ::Hash means look in the global namespace for Hash.  See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855926/in-ruby-how-does-a-class-defined-in-a-module-know-the-modules-constants).

Comment: Just had the same issue inside of a Resque Job class with the Resque Status plugin. Turns out the plugin adds `Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash`

Answer (score 5):

When I added "::" before Hash class it starts working.

```
puts value.class
puts value.is_a?(::Hash)
```

Output:

```
Hash
true
```

Comment: Instead of answering your own question, why not accept the updated answer above from zed_oxff?

Comment: Zed, I've accepted your answer. The truth is that I found answer at the same moment. =) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.

```
dave@hpubuntu1:~ $ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ i386 ]
   jruby-1.6.2 [ linux-i386-java ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ i386 ]

dave@hpubuntu1:~ $ pry
pry(main)> value = {"x" => 3, "y" => 2}
=> {"x"=>3, "y"=>2}
pry(main)> value.is_a? Hash
=> true
```

---

A Mongoid `Hash` isn't a pure-Ruby `Hash`, nor does it extend it. You should check the actual type, probably by using [`type`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Fields/Serializable#type-instance_method).

Just because something prints out `Hash` doesn't mean (a) that it's part of the inheritance chain you think it is, and (b) that it's a `Hash` (witness ActiveRecord `Array`, which lies, to a degree).

Comment: It works in irb, but not in my sample. I've listed whole class source

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov If it's a Mongoid hash you should probably check explicitly for the full class--a Mongoid Hash isn't a Ruby Hash, nor does it extend it. [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Fields/Serializable/Hash)